# Does Ruby have a stepwise debugger, similar to Perl's "perl -d"?

Tags: ruby, debugging

Does Ruby have a stepwise debugger, similar to Perl's "perl -d"?

Answer (score 9):

The [ruby-debug](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug) (for ruby 1.8), [debugger](https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) (for ruby 1.9), [byebug](https://rubygems.org/gems/byebug) (for ruby 2.0) and also the [trepanning](https://rubygems.org/gems/trepanning) series all have an `-x` or `--trace` option. Inside the debuggers, the command `set linetrace` will turn on or off line tracing. Here is [the manual for ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html)

*The original answer has been revised because the link to the datanoise article, alas, no longer works. Also added are the successors to ruby-debug*

Answer (score 1):

From the command line (if you have the `debug` module available):

```
ruby -r debug /path/to/ruby_script.rb
```